# Как сделать чтобы swiper скролил не только слайды а и содержимое в них?

Tags: javascript, html, css, swiper

Есть у меня полноэкранный слайдер, я настроил для него переключение колесеком, тоесть, кручу колесо, переключаются слайды вниз или вверх, но на например на ноутбуках содержимое слайдов не влазит в высоту, я это предусмотрел и дал слайдам overflow: auto, теперь могу скролить содержимое, но мне надо чтобы я мог скролить содержимое слайда с помощью колеса, а не только ползунка, как только я начинаю скролить через колесо содержимое переключаются слайды

Comment: Ну правильно. У Вас же на колесике переключение слайдов стоит, вот они и переключаются по колесику. Сделайте адаптивное изображение, чтоб оно влезло в экран ноутбука и телефона и планшета.

Comment: Я понимаю, но должен же быть способ чтобы я мог проскролить содержимое слайда и когда дойду до его конца при повторном скролле меня должно перекинуть на следующий слайд

Comment: Можно попробовать получить размеры слайда и смещение по Y сравнить их, и только тогда вешать на слайдер событие переключения, а на следующем слайде, опять убрать это событие.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте содержимому слайдов назначить:

```
max-width: 100%;
max-height: 100%;
object-fit: cover;
```

Тогда оно должно вписаться в слайд и скролить колесиком ничего не надо будет. А так на одну и ту же клавишу два события вешать — плохая идея.

Можно еще попробовать написать такой скрипт:

```
let currentSlide = document.querySelector(".slide.active");

let slideHeight = currentSlide.offsetHeight();
let slideScrolledHeight = currentSlide.scrollTop();

if (slideScrolledHeight == slideHeight) // добавляем на слайд переключение колесиком.
```

Comment: окей, но у меня есть много других слайдов на которых множество и текста и фото и других слайдов и они просто не вписывается в высоту 100vh, поэтому нужен скролл

Comment: @vvanyazz дополнил ответ. Вместо .active в Swiper может быть свой класс активности.